# Как в Delphi узнать последнюю строчку своего кода, в котором возникло исключение?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe5

В некоторых случаях при возникновении ошибок, во время отладки, компилятор показывает строчку дельфовых библиотек, где именно возникло исключение. Например обращение к несуществующему индексу массивов и прочих контейнеров, как здесь:

```
  List1 := TList.Create;
  List1.Add(P);
  P := List1.Items[1];
```

Получим указание на строку: `Error(@SListIndexError, Index);` в `System.Classes`

В больших многопоточных проектах отловить подобные ошибки через трассировку бывает крайне сложно, записывать лог после каждой строки - тоже не вариант. А хотелось бы знать строку своего проекта от куда это все началось. Как нибудь можно выявить искомую строку в режиме отладки?

Comment: EurekaLog, MadExcept, еще про JclDebug пишут, и можно самому  написать провайдера для событий возникающих исключений, с помощью чего можно получить информацию о стэке вызовов

Comment: самому писать провайдера, это скорее для разработчиков вышеперечисленных утилит

Comment: Чтобы узнать откуда пришла ошибка, нужно посмотреть на стек вызовов (он же `Call Stack`). В режиме отладки в IDE этот стек всегда доступен и "последняя строчка своего кода" определяется элементарно. Более того, в момент исключения в многопоточном приложении, можно посмотреть в каком конкретном месте находится каждый из потоков и как он в это место попал. Если же вас интересует  вопрос получения стека **не из отладчика**, а имея на руках только скомпилированный `exe`, то тут на помощь приходят указанные выше инструменты (EurekaLog, MadExcept, etc.).

Comment: `Call Stack`, я так понимаю заполняется только во время трассировки с установленными `breakpoint`-ами. У меня по крайней мере в режиме обычной отладки он пуст. Или есть какие-то установки, которые запускают его и в таком режиме?

Comment: @HeathRow конечно пуст, он начнет "работать" когда приложение остановится в какой-нибудь точке. Потому что до постановки приложения на паузу смысла в отладочных окнах нет - параллельно работает несколько потоков, у каждого из которых свой активный Callstack. Сам Callstack покажет последовательность вызовов *текущего* потока в результате брейкпоинта, F4, возникновения исключения. Переключение между потоками с отображением стека каждого - через окно Thread Status

Comment: когда возникнт исключение и в диалоговом окне нажмете `Break`, тогда и будет заполнено окно стека вызовов.

Comment: Теперь все понял. Благодарю всех за помощь.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для этого нужно:

1. Текущее состояние стека. В нем хранится последовательность вызовов функций/процедур (Call Stack), которая привела нас в место возникновения исключения, а также значения всех локальных переменных и входных параметров всех этих функций/процедур.
2. map-файл - информация о том по каким адресам в памяти расположены все наши глобальные переменные, функции/процедуры и их локальные переменные. Он генерируется компилятором.

На основании этих данных можно точно найти то что вам нужно.

Получить всю эту информацию в удобном виде можно либо в процессе отладки встроенным в delphi дебагером, либо с помощью компонентов типа EurekaLog, MadExcept, JclDebug и т.п. получать и сохранять в файл отчета об ошибках самой программой, работающей у клиента.